# R: Plot Rendering Errors

Tags: r, data-visualization, cluster-analysis, render

I am using the R programming language. I am following tutorials from the "mclust" library: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/vignettes/mclust.html

Here, there is an example of gaussian clustering from the tutorial:

```
library(mclust)
data(faithful)
mod5 <- densityMclust(faithful)
plot(mod5, what = "density", type = "hdr",
     data = faithful, points.cex = 0.5)
```

[image]

Everything seems to work fine.

However, when I try to create some artificial data and run the same procedure:

```
a = rnorm(100,10,10)
b = rnorm(100,5,5)
c = data.frame(a,b)

mod5 <- densityMclust(c)
plot(mod5, what = "density", type = "hdr",
     data = c, points.cex = 0.5)
```

This produces an error:

```
Graphics error: Plot rendering error
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You do not seem to do anything wrong - it does work for me (using `set.seed(123)` for reproducibility). Try restarting R with a clean environment, only load `mclust`, maybe use a seed before calling `rnorm` and see if that helps in any way.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I will try again and see what happens

Comment: Update to R-4.0.3 and then run package update from in Rstudio.